# How to make a setter private in Kotlin for non-final variables?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-architecture-components

I need to create a data class like so

```
data class Cat(var toys:Int=3, val type:String):Animal(){
    ...
}
```

Animal is an abstract class with fields for eyes and legs,etc.

I don't want callers to be able to set toys directly. But I want to be able to do some work with toys such as

```
fun addQuota(){toys+=4}
```

how do I complish this cleanly? I still want a public getter, a private settter, but I don't want the variable to be final. And also, this data class is an Entity for Room.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using the property of the constructor as backing field for the `toys` property:

```
data class Cat(val type: String, private var toysField: Int = 3 ):Animal(){

    var toys = toysField
    private set(value){
        toysField = value
    }

    fun addQuota(){toys += 4}

}

abstract class Animal
```

I hope this works with room.

Source https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/private-setter-for-var-in-primary-constructor/3640/10

Comment: thanks for replying. Your answer should definitely work, but I found a simpler solution, which I am providing as an answer as well. Thanks! +1

Comment: I finally got a chance to test this code and it actually doesn't work. Here is the version that works: `var toys = toysField \*\n*/
    private set(value){  \*\n*/
        toysField = value  \*\n*/
    }  \*\n*/
    get()=toysField`

Comment: What part does not work and how does adding the getter change that?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the following works:

```
data class Cat(private var toys:Int=3, val type:String):Animal(){
    ...
    fun getToys()=toys
}
```

Comment: it works, but it's not really idiomatic. the solution with `private set` is preferred

Comment: Hmmm. If the simplest solution is not idiomatic then the idiom is what's wanting not the solution, wouldn't you say? Unless there is a better explanation for why I should use the convoluted `toysField` and then `toys` and then `set(value)`

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you already have found solution that satisfy you, but maybe you can consider this one:

```
class Cat(toys: Int = 3, val type: String) : Animal() {

    var toys = toys
        private set

    fun addQuota() {
        toys += 4
    }

}
```

Comment: I like this one, except it doesn't work for data class

Comment: I believe the only difference between `data` class and usual that data class have inbuilt `toString` and `equals` methods, which you can generate via IDE. Moreover Animal class also can't be data class

Comment: Try it with room without `data`. Android studio still complains.